How do I use the sine series of a function to find the sum of an infinite series?
I have a function $f(x) = x(\pi - x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$. How can I use its sine representation to find the sum of the series;
$1-\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}-\frac{1}{7^3}+\frac{1}{9^3}-\frac{1}{11^3} ...$
I was able to find the sine series which is $\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(nx)}{n^3}$
However, I don't understand what is meant by using the sine representation to find the sum of that series. Will I need to compute $a_n$ and $a_0$ to find $f(x)$?
Or, do I just take a value for $x$ and use $f_o(x)$? Because, I did and I got $\frac{\pi^3}{32}$ but I'm not sure that is what I'm supposed to do.

Find a value for $x$ so that the two series match. You want $\sin(nx)$ to go $1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\dots$ as $n$ goes $1,2,3,4,\dots$

I did that. I used x = pi/2

Yeah so the sine series tells you $f(x)=x(\pi-x)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}$. When $x=\frac\pi2$, this gives you an equation involving the desired series $S$, which you can solve for $S$. Seems like you did it right.
